# how can i display a 3d IRM image with python?

Tags: python, show

I need to display a **3d IRM** image of nifti type (.nii) with python 
I try to use `plt.show()` and `mlab.show()`, but it does not work.
it does not show anything there are no errors

Someone has another method that I can use?

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

img = sitk.ReadImage("IBSR_11_segTRI_ana.nii")
img = np.array(y_pred)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show how you did it and what you mean by "_it does not work_" (ex. you get an error, the image is cropped, etc.).

Comment: What's an IRM? also, what's the file format of the image? if possible, can you give a link where we can get an example image

Answer (score 0):

if it's just an image you are trying to display, you need to read it then display it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('image.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```